# How to move the Search Bar/Div into the Navigation CustomMenu area?

Tags: search

So Far I've done the following;

In catalogsearch.xml I have the following code:

```
<reference name="topMenu">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

then in custommenu/top.phtml I have the following code:

```
<div class="search">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        <div class="sp"></div>
    </div>
```

The top.html code used to be in header.phtml - so I just copied it.

And the reference code  used to say reference name="header" so I just changed it to topMenu, but it doesn't seem  to work!  Am I missing something?

I know that the top.phtml file is correct because if I type in "WHERE IS THIS TEXT" it appears inside the menu area where I want the search bar to go.

However, I'm not sure I am referencing it correctly -  If I reference Top (it displays the search above the menu) - if I reference top.menu (it displays it below the menu).   So I thought It would be topMenu - but it shows nothing.

Could I be referencing it wrong?  Is it reference:  nav-container, or top-menu, or customMenu or something else?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `top.menu` as reference and it should work like charm.